# Meteor Accounts Not Worked In Mobile App (Local)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I have develop application to run mobile os ios and android. Running Android device  for Loading Signup Page. Sighnup cannot worked.May be Accounts ui issue !!

Comment: Please provide more information about your problem. Did you set ROOT_URL correctly? Have you looked at the chrome console log?

Comment: app is running on mobile.then why choose chrome console? i don,'t knoq about ROOT_URL !! ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  the chrome inspector to look at what is happening on the android device.

You also need to understand what ROOT_URL is for, please see this article for an explanation

http://meteorpedia.com/read/Environment_Variables

Comment: my problem is not working meteor accounts in my android device mobile app,but its working on ios similator and web version ?